# How to set context/local variables in power apps

Tags: forms, canvas, formula, powerapps, local-variables

I want to create a power apps form using context variable only like "any user registration". here, i am getting confused how to create a form without adding any data source like SharePoint list.

Please, suggest any solution for this.